# react-image-gallery

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Надо было выложить галлерею на сайт. Сайт пишу на nextjs. Хотел изпользовать готовый модуль. Нашёл на npmjs.com модуль react-image-gallery. Установил, ипорт прописал. Вывожу на страницу в виде функционального компонента, а он мне ругается, что отсутствует метод super или используйте функциональный компопнент. А я же его и использую! Не пойму в чём проблема.Кстати файл TypeScript.

```html
import Image from 'next/image'
import React from 'react'
import styles from './page.module.css'
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import ImageGallery from 'react-image-gallery'
import "react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css";

export default function App() {
  const imagesCrio = [
    {
      original: "/PortfolioImg/crio/001.jpg",
      thumbnail: "/PortfolioImg/crio/001.jpg0"
    },
    {
      original: "/PortfolioImg/crio/002.jpg",
      thumbnail: "/PortfolioImg/crio/002.jpg"
      
    },
    {
      original: "/PortfolioImg/crio/003.jpg",
      thumbnail: "/PortfolioImg/crio/003.jpg"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">   
      <ImageGallery
        items={imagesCrio}
        showPlayButton={true}
        showFullscreenButton={true}
        slideInterval={1000}
        slideOnThumbnailOver={true}
        showIndex={true}
        onPlay={() => {
          alert("slideshow is now playing!");
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```